# 'str' object is not callable, Is There A Fix?

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\joshu\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\HellrazerDevEngine\main.py", line 46, in <module>
game.run()
File "c:\Users\joshu\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\HellrazerDevEngine\main.py", line 41, in run
self.draw()
File "c:\Users\joshu\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\HellrazerDevEngine\main.py", line 29, in draw
self.player.draw()
File "c:\Users\joshu\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\HellrazerDevEngine\player.py", line 45, in draw
pg.draw.line(self.game.screen, 'yellow' (self.x * 100, self.y * 100),
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: This line `pg.draw.line(self.game.screen, 'yellow' (self.x * 100, self.y * 100),` has a syntax error, maybe a `,` is missing after yellow

Answer (score 1):

`pg.draw.line(self.game.screen, 'yellow' (self.x * 100, self.y * 100)`

You have a syntax error in this line. You forgot a comma after `'yellow'`. After this string, you have a pair of brackets, which causes your program to believe that you are calling the string as a function. That explains your TypeError.

Hope this helps.